# How to query for a MS Access column whose name has a question mark, via ODBC?

Tags: ms-access, odbc

I have a MS Access database (Access 2002, for the record).  It has a column whose name contains a question mark, say, for example table "Users" with columns "uid" and "isAdmin?".  I need to connect to this database via ODBC, and query for this column, along the following lines:

```
select [uid], [isAdmin?] from Users order by [isAdmin?];
```

How do I escape the question mark in the column name, so that the MS Access ODBC driver doesn't think that it's a query parameter?  This query doesn't use any parameters, so it's fine if I disable them entirely.

Some limitations:

- I can't easily change the column names.
- I can't easily use something other than ODBC to connect, though this is probably my fallback plan if I can't get ODBC to behave.
- I can't just say `select * from Users` -- it'd still choke on the order by (which is complicated in the real query, so really needs to be done in SQL).

Things I've tried that don't work:

- `select [uid], '[isAdmin?]' from Users;` -- this makes the second column be the string "[isAdmin?]"
- `select [uid], ['isAdmin?'] from Users;`
- `select [uid], [isAdmin\?] from Users;`
- `select [uid], [isAdmin\?] {escape '\'} from Users;` -- nor does any other escape char work.
- `select [uid], { [isAdmin?] } from Users;`

**EDIT**: I should have clarified, I can't easily change the database much at all, except via ODBC (or ADO or DAO or whatever, but that'll be a bit tricky, and at that point I can just run the query through those).

Comment: a question mark in a column name! The guy who authorised it in the MS Access Team should be punished and fed exclusively with MacDo's for the next 10 years!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option would be to create a view of the `Users` table and rename the offending column in the view.

Comment: Good idea, but I forgot to mention that I can't easily change the database at all, except via ODBC.  I imagine that creating the view via ODBC will run into exactly the same trouble with the question mark, unfortunately.

Comment: It turns out I could get an extra non-ODBC connection to the database without too much difficulty, so I could make the view that way (and leave the rest of my code running over ODBC), and so this would have been the most sensible way to go.  However, I managed to avoid the problem completely, so I haven't actually had to try this yet.

Answer (score 3):

This might seem like a devious solution, but it sounds like you're not being given any reasonable help on solving the problem.

Do you have write access to the structure of the MDB? And do you have a copy of standalone Access?

If so, create a new blank MDB file (you will discard this when finished). Create a linked table from the new MDB and use that to write a saved QueryDef that aliases the field. Then use DoCmd.TransferDatabase to export it from your temporary MDB into the real one.

This assumes you have SMB file system access to the MDB that you're accessing from your application via ODBC.

The other alternative, since getting a view with appropriate aliasing into the MDB is a one-shot deal, would be to do this with OLEDB, assuming you have OLEDB access to the MDB.

Comment: I have to say, I like the way you think.

Comment: I hate it when someone asks you to do a job but won't give you the tools and support you need in order to get it done. In that case, doing an end run around the restrictions is fair game, seems to me, even if it is, strictly speaking, "breaking the rules." It's more important to serve the users than it is to follow the rules.

Answer (score 2):

I would use [pass through queries](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303968) and rename the fields in the query. Create your pass through something like

```
 select [uid], [isAdmin?] AS ISADMIN from Users order by [isAdmin?]
```

(or whatever it is in the native SQL),
then in Access, just reference that query

```
select Uid, ISADMIN from qpstUsers
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out passthrough queries, I wasn't terribly aware of them and they may be useful.  Unfortunately, I can't really change the database easily except via ODBC, but maybe I can still set up a passthrough query that way.

Comment: Er, does a passthrough work via ODBC to Jet/ACE? I thought passthroughs were an Access feature, and Access can't connect to a Jet/ACE database via ODBC, so this can't be the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I faced kind of same Issues. (using MS Access driver from SQLdeveloper).

ACCESS SQL does not like '"' as in 
*NOT LIKE "*val*"* 
then I replaced with 
*NOT LIKE '*val*'*

Answer (score 0):

Try this "IsAdmin?"

Double quotes worked in my situation where someone named the column: Lead #

My where clause then became where "Lead #" = '123'

---

I take that back...

where ([Lead #] = 123)

This is what saved me. Notice the parentheses around the clause and the lack of single quotes around my parameter 123. Hope this helps.