# Escape an access table name containing a question mark with ODBC

Tags: java, ms-access, odbc

I have an Access database to query as follows:

```
id - name - Print? 
1  - one  - Yes
2  - two  - No
```

Now my query in java, using the PreparedStatement with an ODBC connector goes something like this:

`select * from table where [Print?] = Yes`

I can't find a way around this to escape the question mark. I know it's an awful design choice by whoever made the database, but it's so tied in applications already changing it is not an option.

PS. I've read [How to query for a MS Access column whose name has a question mark, via ODBC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409610/how-to-query-for-a-ms-access-column-whose-name-has-a-question-mark-via-odbc) but this did not answer my question.

Comment: Have you tried `Statement.executeQuery("select * from table where [Print?] = Yes")` instead of using PreparedStatement ?

Comment: I tried this now - got following error. "[Microsoft][ODBC Text Driver]COUNT field incorrect", which Microsoft says can be solved by: 1. To fix this problem, you must remove the '?' character from the column name(s) fields in the source file. 

Makes me wonder why they allow you to use question mark in access table names but not in ODBC...

Comment: Microsoft logic ...
Do you have the rights to create a view on the database ? As was suggested here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409610/how-to-query-for-a-ms-access-column-whose-name-has-a-question-mark-via-odbc

Comment: I've decided to create another query: qry_print that just selects id and Print? from the table and names the Print? column "Print". 
So pretty much made a view as was suggested in the other answer. Was hoping there would be another way, but I guess sometimes a messy problem requires a messy solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments to the question, apparently the only workaround is to either

- rename the column in the Access table to remove the question mark, or
- create a saved query in Access to return the column with a different name, and then run your JDBC operations against the query, not the table.