# Update Access table containing special character in column name, using Access ODBC driver

Tags: ms-access, odbc

I have the unfortunate circumstance of having to update an older MS Access (.mdb) table using the Access ODBC driver. Everything is working except for one table which has a column name containing a question mark. Specifically this query:

```sql
INSERT INTO TestForm ( Index, [Test?] ) VALUES ( 1, Null )
```

The ODBC driver fails with:

```
ERROR [07002] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]COUNT field incorrect
```

If I take this exact query and run it in MS Access (not through the ODBC driver) it works. Through trial and error I confirmed the problem is the question mark in the column name.

However, I don't have control over the database schema. I cannot modify the schema.

Is there anything I can do to get this to work?

Thanks

Comment: You have a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18593415/escape-an-access-table-name-containing-a-question-mark-with-odbc

Comment: Unfortunate -- neither solution in that thread will work for me. :(

Comment: So you can't create a saved query? Then I don't know how to solve that... sorry

Comment: David-W-Fenton describes an approach in this thread that you might be able to apply: [How to query for a MS Access column whose name has a question mark, via ODBC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409610/how-to-query-for-a-ms-access-column-whose-name-has-a-question-mark-via-odbc)